# C strftime has ending hex characters

Tags: c, strftime

I am trying to add a `Date` header to my HTTP response. So far, I have been doing something like that:

```
char timebuf[37];
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm tm = *gmtime(&now);
strftime(timebuf, sizeof timebuf,"Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z\r\n", &tm);)
```

However, when inspecting timebuf, I am, sometimes (like on the 1st request of the server), receiving a `\x7f` ending character.

Why is that inconsistent? I have double checked the size of timebuf and it should be exactly 37.

Comment: Does exactly 37 include just the text or the NUL terminator as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string you've shown us will result in a string of length 37. *Excluding* the NULL terminator.

Your array should have 38 elements!

Currently your `timebuf` is left unterminated, so you have undefined behaviour anywhere that expects a null-terminated string. That you're seeing `\x7f` sometimes and other characters sometimes (presumably even `\0` sometimes) is just pure chance.

---

From [cppreference.com's C documentation on `strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime):

> Converts the date and time information from a given calendar time `time` to a null-terminated multibyte character string `str` according to format string `format`. Up to `count` bytes are written.

And here are some sums:

```
Substr     Length
---------+--------
"Date: "     6
"%a"         3
", "         2
"%d"         2
" "          1
"%b"         3
" "          1
"%Y"         4
" "          1
"%H"         2
":"          1
"%M"         2
":"          1
"%S"         2
" "          1
"%Z"         4
"\r\n"       2

NULL term.   1
-----------------
         =   38
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was a rookie mistake :) I thought the strcpy coming later would have added the NULL char.